# WPF ResourceDictionary DynamicResource

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

My problem is that I am trying to load a couple of `DrawingImage` from a WPF `ResourceDirectory` with different sets of colours. Resolving those colours fails both with `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource`.

The `ResourceDirectory` in question is never part of the WPF environment (so of any Window, or of the application) because that just does not work in my case. Instead the dictionary is load in code, managed any queried there.

Now the issue is that I got basically three dictionaries. Two for colours (two different palettes) and one that contains the `DrawingImage` definitions. Both of the colour dictionaries contain the the resources with the same names.

So my plan was the load the `DrawingImage` dictionary and once that is done apply the colour dictionary I require as a merged dictionary. It failed. I also tried adding both dictionaries as merged dictionaries to a parent dictonary. That failed too.

I tried loading the dictionaries two ways:

```
Dim palette As New ResourceDictionary()
palette.Source = New Uri("...", UriKind.Relative)
```

and

```
Dim location As New Uri("...", UriKind.Relative)
Dim palette = DirectCast(Application.LoadComponent(location), ResourceDictionary)
```

.

Both yield the same result. The resource dictionaries are loaded, IF I use `DynamicResource` and those resources all resolve to `null`. I think the problem is the method how `DynamicResource` is looking up the resources. But I did not find a way to alter/redirect those lookups to my resource dictionaries.

Is there any way to alter the lookup of `DynamicResource`? Or is there another way to archive what I require?

One thing: Since I develop a library that runs in a larger, third party application, I can't use the global application resource dictionary.

Comment: You load the dicitionary and it doesnt work - the drawing images don't get drawn, correct? But you know in order to load the dictionary you have to add them to the resources of your window/usercontrol and that your code just accesses them? Did you try to isolate your problem, create a new wpf application, create a simple resource dictionary and load it at runtime?

Comment: Loading the resource directories itself works. The resources are properly there, how ever the resource references that cross both dictionaries are not resolved. Getting this to work in a stand alone WPF application is not a issue, the point is: It's *not* a WPF application and I can't attach the resources to any window or user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is a solution to the problem. Using `DynamicResource` works, if a search context is applied. There are two classes that work as search context for this extension. `FrameworkElement` and `FrameworkContentElement`.

The solution is to create one of both and apply all relevant dictionaries to those classes. Once this is done the `DynamicResource`s are properly resolved.

```
Dim drawings As New ResourceDictionary()
drawings.Source = New Uri("...", UriKind.Relative)

Dim palette As New ResourceDictionary()
palette.Source = New Uri("...", UriKind.Relative)

result.MergedDictionaries.Add(drawings)
result.MergedDictionaries.Add(palette)
Dim fe As New FrameworkElement()
fe.Resources = result
```

Once the dictionary is assigned to the resources of the `FrameworkElement` fetching the resources works as expected.